# Downloading multiple images from Firebase Storage in Unity and displaying each of them on different objects

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download several images from Firebase Storage then display them on separate objects. I use Firestore to store the string data and Storage to store the images accordingly. So on Panel A, we have string A and Image A, Panel B with String B and Image B, etc. So far I've managed to instantiate the prefabs with the according strings but I haven't found any solutions for the images

This code below is for retrieving data from firestore

```
    public void PrintDataTestWithImage()
    {
        DestroySearchedObject();
        Query storeRef = db.Collection("Store").Document(storedata).Collection("Costumes");
        storeRef.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            QuerySnapshot storeRefSnapshot = task.Result;
            foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in storeRefSnapshot.Documents)
            {
                CostumeDatabase costume = documentSnapshot.ConvertTo<CostumeDatabase>();
                SpawnWithImageTest(costume.CostumeName, costume.Franchise, costume.Size, costume.Price, costume.LingkarPinggang, costume.LingkarDada);
            }
        });
    }
```

The function below is called each time a documentSnapshot is retrieved (This one is for displaying string data and the according image)

```
  public void SpawnWithImageTest(string name, string franch, string size, int price, int waist, int chest)
    {
        GameObject child = Instantiate(CostumePrefab);
        child.transform.SetParent(PanelHolder.transform, false);
        GameObject NameReq = child.transform.Find("Panel").transform.Find("CostName").gameObject;
        GameObject FranchiseReq = child.transform.Find("Panel").transform.Find("Franch").gameObject;
        GameObject SizeReq = child.transform.Find("Panel").transform.Find("Size").gameObject;
        GameObject PriceReq = child.transform.Find("Panel").transform.Find("Price").gameObject;
        GameObject CostImage = child.transform.Find("RawImage").gameObject;

        ReqName = NameReq.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        ReqFranchise = FranchiseReq.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        ReqSize = SizeReq.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        ReqPrice = PriceReq.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        costImage = CostImage.GetComponent<RawImage>();


        ReqName.text = name;
        ReqFranchise.text = franch;
        ReqSize.text = string.Format("{0} (W: {1} C: {2}) ", size, waist.ToString(), chest.ToString());
        ReqPrice.text = price.ToString();

        string filename = string.Format("{0}.jpeg", ConvertNameToFileName(name, storedata));
        StorageReference imgcost = storageReference.Child(string.Format("uploads/{0}", filename));
         imgcost.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if(!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled){
                StartCoroutine(LoadImage(System.Convert.ToString(task.Result), costImage)); //Fetch file from the link
            }
            else{
                Debug.Log(task.Exception);
            }
        });
    }
```

The IEnumerator is used to download the image. I've tried using byte[] but it didn't download the image

```
IEnumerator LoadImage(string MediaUrl, RawImage img)
    {
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(MediaUrl); //Create a request
        Debug.Log(MediaUrl);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest(); //Wait for the request to complete
        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            img.texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
            // setting the loaded image to our object
        }
    }
```

[I want to display images to all those panels but the images only appear on the last panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQzjd.png)

[This what I'm expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMY0Q.png)

Comment: probably not solving the issue but you could make your live a bit easier using a proper component on the `CostumePrefab` already referencing all the required sub-components in serialized fields so you can simply access them directly without all those hard coded `Find` and `GetComponent` calls

Comment: Could you post your logs? It might make it easier to debug. Additionally, where is `storageReference` defined?

Comment: The thing is, there's no log that tells anything. But it somehow works by retrieving the image first then set the firestore data

Comment: What happens if you null check the `.texture`?